# Can I add an existing 2008 build server to new TFS 2010 server?

Tags: msbuild, build-server

My scenario is this: I am currently testing out a new Team Foundation Server 2010 installation; which we will be moving to shortly.

Upgrading builds to work with TFS 2010 and the new MSBuild seems like a lot of work (it does not work out-of-the-box, at least). So what I would like to do, is to repurpose our old TFS Server to be a build server for TFS 2010. It already has build services installed.

I cannot figure out how to add an existing TFS 2008 Build Server to my new TFS 2010 installation, so I can use the old server to run old builds. Is this possible ? How can I do it ?

Comment: Hopefully someone proves me wrong below, but as far as I know, this combination is not possible.  A TFS 2010 server can only use TFS 2010 build agents...though they're both on the same port etc (even on the same machine this works), they are not compatible.  What issues did you have with MSBuild 4?  Probably quicker to solve those problems than this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only connect a TFS 2010 build server to TFS 2010. I think you may be hosed as I think the installer for TFS 2010 will want to upgrade your TFS 2008 instance.

Is there any reason you are keeping TFS 2008 around?

Why not remove TFS 2008 and install the TFS 2010 build service?

Comment: I had the idea to re-use the old TFS as a build server, because my upgraded builds would not run after the upgrade. Partly because they utilize the MSBuild community tasks.

We have a guy going through the builds now and figuring out what we need to do to make them work on TFS 2010.

Comment: It is always for the best to ditch the old ways for the new: When the new ways become the old ways, the old ways become the realy old ways.